# Cordova mobile missing files of my project

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

Im working right now on a hybrid app on cordova and I have my project on the WWW folder with some html files and and images folder and a assetes folder; when I do `cordova build android` `cordova run android` the app get installed on my phone witch is connected to my pc for debugging. the is running and I see the index page, when I want to access to a login.html page I get 404 error and I noticed that the images are not loaded. So I called the dev tool of chrome to see the sources section, what I got is only the index.html and the assets folder, no login.html no images folder. when I do run the app on the browser I get every thing as expected 
how to explain this?

Comment: could you please check whether these files (login.html and images) are copied into `platforms/android/assets`. If not, try to reinstall platform (`cordova platform rm android && cordova platform add android`)

Comment: I see in `platforms/android/assets/www` the same content as in the www

Comment: I did re install android but nothing changed I even moved `myapp/www/images` to `myapp/www/assetes/images` but the folder is still not showing up when I `build` and `run` the app